# Unable to Write Swift Dictionary to NSUserDefaults in Beta 5

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have been working on an app in which I user NSUserDefaults to persist a Dictionary for use elsewhere in the program.  This  been working perfectly since Beta 1.  Now with the latest update (beta 5) this no longer works.  It appears they have removed the ability to persist a swift Dictionary in this manner.  However, I can persist an NSDictionary.  Here is a code snippet that worked 2 days ago and now is broken.

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(allPlayersDict, forKey: "playerDict")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

This code does not write anything to the NSUserDefaults, not even the key, when checked using:

```
var testDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()
println(testDict)
```

Has anyone else experienced this or have a solution?

Comment: any messages in the console or does it just fail silently?

Comment: better to file a bug with apple

Comment: It just fails silently without complaint.

Comment: Bug report 17939471 filed.

Comment: It is possible to write Swift `String` and `NSArray` of `String`. Ex that work: `defaults.setObject("obj2", forKey:"key")` and `defaults.setObject(["val3", "val4"] as NSArray, forKey: key)`