# How to save [AnyObject!] = [] in NSUserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode6

I need save a variable of type:

```
  var array1: [AnyObject!] = []
```

I tried this but isn't save:

```
    var key = "keySave"
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    array1.append(["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"])
    array1.append(["key2": "val3", "key4": "val4"])

    defaults.setObject(array1, forKey: key)
    defaults.synchronize()
```

Need I cast this variables to other type of data? What is the correct form to make this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use `AnyObject!`, that means the values can be nil, but they only should be until first initialized. You should not add an object which is not initialized. Use `[AnyObject]`.

Comment: ok, I change this, but this doesn't affect to save or not save the array.

Comment: Instead of trying to use `NSUserDefaults` ass NSCoding support to your chase and save ti using `NSArchiving`. Using `NSUserDefaults` is not a best practice for general persistence, `NSArchiving` is.

Comment: let array1:NSDictionary = ["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"] as NSDictionary this also not saved in userdefaults

Comment: `let dictionary:NSDictionary = ["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"] as NSDictionary` cast is also not working in swift.May be this is bug in `Xcode Beta 5`

Comment: This is bug in Xcode beta 5 refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153754/unable-to-write-swift-dictionary-to-nsuserdefulats-in-beta-5

Comment: I do this ,  'code' var userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION) where mdmiosagent_constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION = "com.apple.configuration.managed".. I get an error like cannot convert type [NSObject:AnyObject] to NSUserDefaults. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not allowed. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:) of `NSUserDefaults` class, only these specific types are supported by `setObject:forKey:` method:

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. For `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects, their contents must be property list objects.

You can fix this by replacing a Swift array with `NSMutableArray`, a subclass of the allowed `NSArray` class.

Comment: I would think the *type compability* would allow it, since I can use String, where NSString is wanted (likewise with Array, Dictionary, Int and so on). But **maybe it is not allowed in this special case**.

Comment: @ViktorLexington Since the documentation mentions classes by name, rather than saying something more general (say, "anything conforming to `NSCoding` protocol" or something similar) I suspect that `NSUserDefaults` uses very type-specific implementation, perhaps even with a chain of if-then-elses checking the exact types.

Comment: This is bug in xcode beta 5 and i think your answer is not correct.It is working in beta 4.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `let dictionary:NSDictionary = ["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"] as NSDictionary` cast is also not working in swift.May be this is bug

Comment: It looks like `NSUserDefaults` does not support Swift types other than `String`.

Comment: Then... Is this impossible?? I think that should be some forms to make that I want.. Do you know any gitHub project that makes something similar? Thanks!!

Comment: @user3745888 I do not know any gitHub projects in Swift that would do any of this. From codester comments it sounds like you should be able to do it if you use straight Cocoa types for everything, downgrade to beta 4, or wait for the compatibility bug to be fixed.